# Reading shorts and chars from file

Tags: java, file-io, unicode

I have a binary file which is a list of 2 byte integer and UTF-8 char pairs. What I'm doing is

```
InputStream stream = ...;
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(stream);

while(...){
   stream.read(...);
   in.read();
}
```

That is, I read bytes from InputStream directly and I read chars from InputStreamReader of the  same file stream. This looks like an odd (awful?) idea to me, but I don't see another way. DataInputStream will only read UTF-16 chars and I don't know how many bytes my UTF-8 char will take to read it from bytes myself (I wouldn't want to reinvent InputStreamReader). Also, the same scheme worked with output.

My problem is that after reading the first pair, InputStream.read returns -1 (of course, the file is longer than that).

I want to know if there are better alternatives or if there could have been another cause for EOF. Also, in case this scheme is okay, should I be closing the Reader or the InputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you don't want to access both an InputStreamReader and its underlying InputStream.  You probably do have to write your own version of InputStreamReader, but it's not a lot to write:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(stream);
while (dataStream.available() > 0) {
    int intValue = dataStream.readUnsignedShort();

    int charValue;
    int b = dataStream.read();
    if (b < 0x80) {
        charValue = b;
    }
    else {
        int byteCount;
        if (b >= 0xf0) {
            byteCount = 4;
        } else if (b >= 0xe0) {
            byteCount = 3;
        } else {
            byteCount = 2;
        }

        bytes[0] = (byte) b;
        dataStream.readFully(bytes, 1, byteCount - 1);
        String s = new String(bytes, 0, byteCount, 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        charValue = s.codePointAt(0);
    }

    // Do something with intValue and charValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You probably meant `readUnsignedByte()` though, as there doesn't seem to be a `read` like that in `DataInputStream`.

Comment: The `readUnsignedShort` method is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedShort%28%29).

Comment: DataInputStream inherits the read() method from InputStream.  From what I can tell, the only difference between read() and readUnsignedByte() is that readUnsignedByte() can't return -1, so you are correct that readUnsignedByte() is a better choice.